# Inequality between continuous functions holding almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity, almost-everywhere

Take two continuous functions $f,g$ ( for simplicity say $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$).

If we know $$f\leq g~~ \text{almost everywhere (w.r.t the Lebesgue measure).}$$

Then does it follow that

$$ f(t) \leq g(t) ~~\text{for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$}.$$

---

Does anyone have a counter-example or a proof of this statement?

The reason I hoped this to be true is from the continuity of $f,g$ if : $g(s) < f(s)$ for some $s$ then there will be a small ball around $s$ where for each $t$ in such a ball $g(t)<f(t)$ - which is a contradiction. I struggled to prove this though.

Answer (score 1):

All non-empty open sets have, indeed, strictly positive Lebesgue measure and $\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, g(x)<f(x)\}$ is open.